how can i find the least time interval clustering for different multipliers in a way to correlate the most two similar time data series?
So, as the title says, i want to equalize/correlate the maximum i can the first time data series by clustering the minimum time intervals with their respective multipliers to basically match to best i can the second time data series.
I would like to know what type of approach I could take on this problem and/or what type of algorithm i could use to find the solution.
For example, lets say I have this two data sets:
A = {1,3,5,7,9,11}

B = {2,6,10,14,18,22}

The solution for this would be:
There is only 1 possible solution which is to apply only one commom multiplier (2) on the A data series to match the B data series on a correlation of 100%
Other example (more realistic):
A = {1,3,5,7,9,11}

B = {2,6,10,21,27,33}

The solution for this would be:
Apply on the first time interval (first 3 positions) multiplier of 2; and apply on the rest (last 3) multiplier of 3, to reach a perfect match.
The approach also could be using 6 time intervals and each one use the correspondent multiplier, but i want to cluster to the max the time intervals to multiply by the same number those time interval clusters.
I've already tried to search for the best algorithm for this, but i cant find any (or maybe it is because i have to apply more than 1)...
Basically, the solution would be given as a graph, where x is number of clusters and y is similarity between the two time series (saying both sets have a length of 1000, 1000 clusters with their respective multiplier each would be a 100% similarity, and 1 cluster only, would be the less similarity of them all). The thing here is to find the best optimized number of clusters (minimum as posible) and the maximum similarity.
